# Wordpress - thumbnail image from youtube (function and loop)

Tags: functions, loop, query-posts

Hi :D i need show thumbnails from youtube in homepage, i have a code for wordpress in function and the loop but not working thumbnail from youtube. What can be wrong with the code?

Function Code:

```
  function get_thumbnail_fromyoutube( $size = 0 ) {
      global $post, $posts;
      $youtube = '';
      $get_url = preg_match_all('/<iframe.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
      $youtube = $matches[1][0];
      if(preg_match('/^(http:\/\/www.youtube.com)/', $youtube))
      {
        $youtube = preg_replace('/(.*?).embed\//', '', $youtube);
        $youtube = preg_replace('/\?.(.*?)$/', '', $youtube);
        echo '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $youtube . '/' . $size . '.jpg" alt="' . $post->post_title . '" />';
      }

    }
```

LOOP CODE:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'taxonomy' => 'section',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'video'


        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

         ?>


<img src="<?php echo has_post_thumbnail() ? the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') : get_thumbnail_fromyoutube(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
<?php

                        }
                      }

                    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
                    ?>
```

Comment: You should have a look at [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/video-thumbnails/). I don't like recommending plugins, but for this purpose I think this will be the best.

Comment: I'll take a look at the plugin, tried to make the website in wordpress without plugin
 will work for custom post?

Answer (score -2):

Well, assuming the post content will be provided by Youtube embedded code, a change in the regular expression is needed.

The function must obtain the source of the iframe. So would be as follows:

```
function get_thumbnail_fromyoutube( $size = 0 ) {
global $post, $posts;
$youtube = '';
$get_url = preg_match_all('/src="([^"]+)"/', $post->post_content, $matches);
$youtube = $matches[1][0];
var_dump($youtube);
if(preg_match('/^(http:\/\/www.youtube.com)/', $youtube)) {
    $youtube = preg_replace('/(.*?).embed\//', '', $youtube);
    $youtube = preg_replace('/\?.(.*?)$/', '', $youtube);
    echo '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $youtube . '/' . $size . '.jpg" alt="' . $post->post_title . '" />';
}
```

}

Where the variable "get_url" stores the URL of the video.

And always remember to remove the "img" tag inside the Loop, leaving only the conditional statement.

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) ? the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') : get_thumbnail_fromyoutube(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi @javierguillen29 not working :/

Comment: not working my friend

Comment: no image shows on the loop, his loop code did not work I had to replace it with this, but does not work anyway. 

`<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {  the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); get_thumbnail_fromyoutube(); }  ?>`

in post content i use embed code provided by youtube (iframe)

Comment: and if i add this your code in function and in the loop i add this code `<img src="<?php echo get_thumbnail_fromyoutube() ?>"/>`

the result is the html code is 

`<img "="" 8rdcbpcejzq"="" embed="" www.youtube.com="" src="string(35) ">`